# If $\chi(g)$ generates a dense subgroup of $\chi(G)$ for all $\chi$ then $g$ generates a dense subgroup of $G$.

Tags: topological-groups, ergodic-theory

This question arised from something in Ergodic theory, however this is not necessary to state or answer the question.

Suppose that $G$ is a compact abelian group and $g\in G$.

Are the following two equivalent:

1. For every continuous character $\chi:G\rightarrow S^1$, $\chi(g)$ generates a dense subgroup of $\chi(G)$.
2. $g$ generates a dense subgroup of $G$.

Clearly $2$ implies $1$, but I can't figure out whether the opposite holds.

For those who are interested in the connection with ergodic theory. Property $2$ means that $(G,R_g)$ is an ergodic system, and I ask whether this is equivalent to property 1 which means that all the factors $(\chi(G),R_{\chi(g)})$ are ergodic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short proof: if 2 fails, the group $G/\overline{\langle g\rangle}$ is a nontrivial compact abelian group and hence has a nontrivial continuous character $\chi$. Then $\chi(g)=1$ generates the trivial subgroup, which is not dense in $\chi(G)$, so 1 fails.

Comment: This is no different than the answer above is it?

Comment: @Yanko yes you're right. I didn't notice that there were two answers in your post, and thought a briefer one would be useful, but actually it's the same argument with slightly different wording. (PS beginning of your answer "is non-trivial" should be "is a proper subgroup".)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **Yes**!.

Suppose by contradiction that $1$ holds but $2$ doesn't. Let $H=\overline{\left<g\right>}$, then by assumption $H\leq G$ is a proper subgroup.

Look at $G/H$. This is a non-trivial group and so admits a non-trivial character $\chi:G/H\rightarrow S^1$. We may compose with $G\rightarrow G/H$ to obtain a character $\tilde{\chi}:G\rightarrow S^1$ which is trivial on $H$. In particular $\tilde{\chi}(g)$ is trivial, however $\tilde{\chi}(G) = \chi(G/H)$ is a non-trivial subgroup of $S^1$ - contradiction.

This completes the proof.

**Edit:** I just figured even another answer for that!

Let $s\in G$, for all $\chi\in\hat G$ there exists a net $n_\alpha$ such that $\chi(g^{n_\alpha})\rightarrow \chi(s)$.

Using a diagonal argument we can choose the same sub-net $n_\beta$ for all characters, also by moving into a sub-sub-net if necessary we may assume that $g^{n_\beta}\rightarrow h\in G$. Since all the characters are continuous we have that $\chi(h)=\chi(s)$ for all $\chi$. Using the fact that characters separates points we have that $h=s$, which means that $g^{n_\beta}$ converges to $s$. In particular $s\in \overline{\left<g\right>}$

Comment: I think you should be talking about nets rather than sequences

Comment: @mathworker21 I don't understand the comment. I mean I know what's a net but I don't see why it is relevant here.

Comment: How do you know "there exists a *sequence* $n_k$ such that $\chi(g^{n_k}) \to \chi(s)$"?

Comment: @mathworker21 $\chi(s)$ lies in the closure of $\{\chi(g^n):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. You're right that $n_k$ is not necessarily increasing (we can assume it is increasing but not monotonically increasing). Is that your point?

Comment: No. My point is that in topological spaces, a point $x$ lies in the closure of a set $E$ iff there is a net $x_\alpha$ of points in $E$ converging to $x$. I wonder how you could think my object is to the $n_k$'s being increasing, when I brought up nets.

Comment: @mathworker21 Oh right I see now, looks like I assumed that $G$ is metric. You're totally right I'll add that thanks.

Comment: no problem. sub-sub-sequence --> sub-sub-net